# CodeIgniter returns letter 'x' before correct response

Tags: php, codeigniter, httprequest, httpresponse, codeigniter-3

When I am making requests to my controller that extends REST_Controller, using CodeIgniter 3, every response that I get starts with a letter 'x'. And of course this isn't me that are returning this. For example if I set up a test method like this

```
function test_get() {
    $this->response(array('test field' => 'test value'));
}
```

And try to make this request from for example [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) or an Android/iOS application or whatever the response I get looks like this.

```
x{"test field":"test value"}
```

Even if I try to access a method that doesn't exist, i.e. nothing that I have done is called. I get this response

```
x{"status":false,"error":"Unknown method"}
```

The 'x' is still there. I can't remember that it always been like this, so probably I have managed to change something somewhere. But where could this be happening, is it somewhere in super classes? I have tried looking there but haven't found anything yet. Or what could cause this to happen?

Comment: You probably typed an x somewhere by mistake in of the core files that is used to create each response. Try doing a clean reinstall of the CI core code.

Comment: Yes I also thought about that, but where could this be? What is the flow for creating the response, so I could follow the trail back and find it

Comment: The x was not sended from codeigniter app, the x will be in your Android/IOS code

Comment: @elddenmedio No I don't think so, because as I wrote in my post, I get the 'x' from Postman which is a desktop application. I also get it from iOS application